# Why are decimal and hexadecimal integer literals treated differently?

Tags: c++, types, integer, constants, literals

Reading Stanley Lippman's "C++ Primer", I learned that by default decimal integer literals are signed (smallest type of `int`, `long` or `long long` in which the literal's value fits) whereas octal and hexadecimal literals can be either signed or unsigned (smallest type of `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long` or `unsigned long long` in which the literal's value fits) .

What's the reason for treating those literals differently?

Edit: I'm trying to provide some context

```
int main()
{
    auto dec = 4294967295;
    auto hex = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    return 0;
}
```

Debugging following code in Visual Studio shows that the type of `dec` is `unsigned long` and that the type of `hex` is `unsigned int`.
This contradicts what I've read but still: both variables represent the same value but are of different types. That's confusing me.

Comment: Please give some context.

Comment: Because when a programmer dealing with non-decimal literal, it is usually for some kind of bit manipulations, where the sign is not important, but the physical representation.

Comment: I actually thought integer literals are always int/unsigned int and can overflow, because GCC warns about it.

Comment: @user3528438 It warns because signed overflow is undefined. `-1 < 10` will always return true, so it is signed.

Comment: This sure sounds specific enough to be mentioned in the C specifications somewhere. I always thought of number notation as ... neutral. Surely `02` is the same as `2` and `0x2`?

Comment: The literal value you give does not drive the variable type: that comes first.

Comment: @WeatherVane C Standard: "The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can
be represented."

Comment: @AlexD Right, apparently OP mistakenly used a C tag on a C++ question.

Comment: In terms of `auto` and the type selected, you may have encountered a Visual Studio bug.

Comment: "This contradicts what I've read " - what did you read? It is correct according to what you said in your first paragraph.

Comment: @M.M I thought (according to my first paragraph) that decimal literals can only be of the types `int`, `long` or `long long`. So `dec` shouldn't be an `unsigned int` but according to the Visual Studio debugger it is.

Comment: You're right that decimal literals can only be signed types *if the literal fits in a signed type*.  If it doesn't then it's undefined behaviour. Prior to C++11 which added `long long`, the `4294967295` did not fit in any signed type so it was undefined behaviour (which can be manifested as generating an unsigned literal of some type, or anything else).  C++11 didn't change the nature of the rules, it just added `long long int` to the list.  If your compiler is supposed to be C++11-complaint (VS2013 and later?) and it does what you said then it is non-conforming, which might be deliberate

Comment: I think C89 defined that the literal would be `unsigned long` in this case, so MS may have shared code between their C and C++ compilers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++.2011 changed its promotions rules from C++.2003. This change is documented in §C.2.1 [diff.cpp03.lex] :

> 2.14.2
>   **Change**: Type of integer literals
>   **Rationale**: C99 compatibility

The C Standard, both C.1999 and C.2011, defines the conversions in §6.4.4.1. (C++.2011 §2.14.2 essentially copies the content from the C Standard.)

> The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can
>   be represented.
>
> [image]
>   <sub>[larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QIKB.png)</sub>

The C.1999 rationale gives the following explanation:

> The C90 rule that the default type of a decimal integer constant is either `int`, `long`, or
>   `unsigned long`, depending on which type is large enough to hold the value without overflow,
>   ***simplifies the use of constants.*** The choices in C99 are `int`, `long` and `long long`.
>   C89 added the suffixes `U` and `u` to specify unsigned numbers. C99 adds `LL` to specify `long long`.
>
> Unlike decimal constants, octal and hexadecimal constants too large to be `int`s are typed as
>   `unsigned int` if within range of that type, since it is ***more likely that they represent bit
>   patterns or masks, which are generally best treated as unsigned, rather than “real” numbers***.

Comment: The c++ standards states: **Change: Type of integer literals. Rationale: C99 compatibility.** for the changes in c++11. p 1245 N3797.  Feel free to include it in your answer. The tags are now c++ only.