# What is the meaning of _BIG_ENUM=0xFFFFFFFF, in the last of the enum?

Tags: c, enums

I am reading some codes and I found this _BIG_ENUM=0xFFFFFFFF in the last value of the enum.what is the correct meaning of this line. And this  _BIG_ENUM is not used anywhere in the code;

```
#define CLS_COMM_CONFIG PORT_0,BAUD_9600,DATA_BIT_8,ONE_STOP,NO_FLOW_CONTROL
#define PLS_COMM_CONFIG PORT_1,BAUD_115200,DATA_BIT_8,ONE_STOP,NO_FLOW_CONTROL

typedef enum _comm_config
{

 _Zero=0,
 PORT_0=_Zero,
 BAUD_2400=_Zero,
 NONE=_Zero,
 HALF_STOP=_Zero,
 DATA_BIT_5=_Zero,
 NO_FLOW_CONTROL=_Zero,

 _One = 1,
 PORT_1=_One,
 BAUD_4800=_One,
 ODD=_One,
 ONE_STOP=_One,
 DATA_BIT_6=_One,

 _Two=2,
 PORT_2=_Two,
 BAUD_9600=_Two,
 EVEN=_Two,
 TWO_STOP=_Two,
 DATA_BIT_7=_Two,

 _Three=3,
 PORT_3=_Three,
 BAUD_19200=_Three,
 DATA_BIT_8=_Three,

 _Four=5,
 PORT_5=_Four,
 BAUD_115200=_Four,
 DATA_BIT_9=_Four,

 _BIG_ENUM=0xFFFFFFFF,

}COMMConfig;
```

Comment: Please don't radically change the question once there are answers posted. I did a rollback of your changes.

Comment: Actually why does the question title say one thing and the code another thing? ...

Comment: Note also the `_BIG_ENUM` is a reserved identifier per [**7.1.3 Reserved identifiers**, paragraph 1 of the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3):  "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use."  As a reserved identifier, its use is improper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense and is a bug.

I suppose the programmer didn't quite know how enums work and thought they could enforce enums to become 32 bit by assigning a large integer constant to one of the enumeration constants. This is true, but they picked a bad value which won't work as they thought it would.

The problem is that while enumeration *variables* may have implementation-defined sizes, enumeration *constants* such as `_BIG_ENUM` are *always* of type `int` <sup>1)</sup>.

But `0xFFFFFFFF` won't fit in a 32 bit `int` so this is a bug. The hex constant `0xFFFFFFFF` is actually of type `unsigned int` (assuming 32 bit) and it won't fit, so there will be an implementation-defined conversion from signed to unsigned. Meaning we end up with the value `-1` on 2's complement systems. Although gcc and clang with strict standard settings even refuse to compile the code when the enumeration constant is given an integer constant larger than `INT_MAX`.

When faced with an enumeration constant of value `-1`, the compiler is free to pick any signed type<sup>2)</sup> for enumeration variables of that type, not necessarily a 32 bit one.

The code can be fixed by changing it to `_BIG_ENUM=INT_MAX,` (limits.h). Then the enumerated type will either become `int` or `unsigned int`.

---

<sup>1)</sup> C17 6.7.2.2/1

> The expression that defines the value of an enumeration constant shall be an integer constant expression that has a value representable as an `int`.

<sup>2)</sup> C16 6.7.2.2/4

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with `char`, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined,128) but shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration.
>
> 128) An implementation may delay the choice of which integer type until all enumeration constants have
>   been seen.

Comment: Reading in detail and this in particular _1453 108) An implementation may delay the choice of which integer type until all enumeration constants have been seen._ means that the compiler could choose `unsigned int` apparently. Although I understand your point, it appears that it's possible that with some compiler this trick was working fine. But we don't know whether this code compiled with a specific compiler or not.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi No it cannot because the enumeration constant `_BIG_ENUM` is assigned the value -1.

Comment: Re "*But 0xFFFFFFFF won't fit in a 32 bit int*", Indeed. [Unsigned hexadecimal constant in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4737798/589924)

Comment: @Iharob Al Asimi, You're confusing the type of the `enum` (which is flexible) and the  type of the expression that defines the value of the constant (which isn't).

Comment: @ikegami Yes, the original code will not compile with strict settings on gcc because of that bug.

Comment: @ikegami That's exactly what is happening to me. You are both right. I wouldn't have thought of ever doing such a thing, but I attempted to understand the situation from the standard and got confused with that exactly. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: BTW gcc's error message is pretty clear about the fact that the problem is the value of the constant. You need `-pedantic` though. I do use `-pedantic` regularly.

Answer (score 3):

Some compilers can optimize enum to smaller word-sizes, but this could cause problem with interoperability when not all of the code is compiled with the same compiler.

If an enum is assigned a 32-bit value this optimization is prevented, forcing this enum to be encoded as a 32 bit integer.

Comment: Why did anyone downvote this? It's a fine answer and I suspect it is correct.

Comment: This is wrong since 0xFFFFFFFF won't fit inside an enumeration constant. Enumeration constants are always `int` and can't get different sizes, unlike enumeration variables.

Comment: @Lundin, Why do you say 0xFFFFFFFF doesn't fit in a (32-bit) `int`?

Comment: @Lundin check this https://embedded.fm/blog/2016/6/28/how-big-is-an-enum and this http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.7.2.2.html precisely the last sentence.

Comment: @Iharob Al Asimi, That's not what Lundin is disagreeing with

Comment: @Lundin, if I remember correctly this is an issue if you use both RVCT and gcc in the same project

Comment: @ikegami Actually the comment says that 32bit integers are too large for an enum. The truth is that the compiler might choose smaller integer sizes, apparently never more than 32bit which isn't guaranteed either, the only thing that is 100% sure is that it's maximum `sizeof(int)` but then the post lacks information about whether or not there are tests that ensure this will not cause problems.

Comment: @Iharob Al Asimi, No they said `0xFFFFFFFF` doesn't fit in a 32-bit int. Their first comment (on the question itself) is clearer (" But `0xFFFFFFFF` won't fit in a 32 bit int")

Comment: An issue with RVCT 3.1, where they apparently had not read @Lundin's post about integer enums  http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1360774870320.htm this hack would trick this compiler

Comment: @Simson From the link: "In strict C, enumerator values must be representable as ints. That is, they must be in the range -2147483648 to +2147483647, inclusive. A warning is issued for out-of-range enumerator values". So Keil appears to behave just as gcc and clang.

Comment: "An object of type enum is implemented in the smallest integral type that contains the range of the enum. " - this is what caused this mess - and I totally agree enum-s are nonsense in embedded C.